# Java Parameter issue for Data Provider

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation

I want to use multiple columns of excelsheet and pass it on Java Method as parameters. But it is not allowing to add more than 2 parameters as I hv used Data Providers. Now is there any other way, through which I can have multiple parameters or I can pass it as an object. I want to fill multiple data from sheet defined as columns. It is throwing error like, "The data provider is trying to pass 5 parameters but the method com.indracarelis.testscript.admin.NewOrder#CreateNewOrder takes 2". Which are the two parameters it use for a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have written the code for fetching the data from Excel in the `@DataProvider`

You can create an HashMap containing the  pair and pass it on to the test. Psuedo code below:

```
@DataProvider(name ="abc")
public static Object[][] getData() {
    //code to read excel file goes here
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap();

    data.put("Column1","data1");
    data.put("Column2","data2");
    data.put("Column3","data3");
    return new Object[] {data};
}

@Test(dataProvider="abc", dataProviderClass=TestClass.class)
public void test(HashMap<String, String> data) {
    //use data here
}
```